# Add audio and subtitle in mkv video by one command

Tags: ffmpeg

Add audio and subtitle in mkv video by one command.

Code add subtitle:

```
-i input.mkv -f srt -i subtitle.srt -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s srt -c:s:0 srt -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng output.mkv
```

Code add audio:

```
-i input.mkv -i audio.aac -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 1:a -metadata:s:a:1 language=eng  -codec copy output.mkv
```

I couldn't add subtitle and audio in one command.Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't map everything

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i input.aac -i input.srt -map 0:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 2:0 -map 1:a -c copy output.mkv
```

But it is unclear which one to map, you took different stream each time from the mkv `-map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2` vs `-map 0:v -map 0:a:0`